# Android Java ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission retrieving ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, location

I have an application that requires to use Fine Location, when I request Fine Location permissions, the dialog does not ask for accurate location, only approximate location.

I have tried on several devices, an Android Studio Emulator, on a Huawei and it does ask for permissions correctly, but when I try on a Samsung Galaxy A32 phone, it doesn't show me the accurate location option.

This is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="***">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Request Permission

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.d("message", "permission denied");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Dashboard.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
    return;
}
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` declaration from manifest and try, else request for both `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

> If you try to request only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the system ignores the request on some releases of Android 12

Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request)

Answer (score 0):

First ask for COARSE location.

And only after the user allowed that ask for FINE.